# How to get the N most recent dates in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to get the most 30 recent days worth of records for each grouping of data in Pyspark? In this example, get the 2 records with the most recent dates within the groupings of (Grouping, Bucket). So a table like this

```
| Grouping | Bucket | Date      |
|----------|--------|-----------|
| 1        | 1      | 9-20-2020 |
| 1        | 1      | 9-16-2020 |
| 1        | 1      | 8-14-2020 |
| 1        | 2      | 9-20-2020 |
| 1        | 2      | 9-16-2020 |
| 1        | 2      | 8-14-2020 |
| 2        | 1      | 9-20-2020 |
| 2        | 1      | 9-16-2020 |
| 2        | 1      | 8-14-2020 |
```

Would turn into this:

```
| Grouping | Bucket | Date      |
|----------|--------|-----------|
| 1        | 1      | 9-20-2020 |
| 1        | 1      | 9-16-2020 |
| 1        | 2      | 9-20-2020 |
| 1        | 2      | 9-16-2020 |
| 2        | 1      | 9-20-2020 |
| 2        | 1      | 9-16-2020 |
```

Edit: I reviewed my question after edit and realized that not doing the edit to begin with was the right choice

Comment: Have you tried to filter the date column by today - 30days? e.g. using `date_sub`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have not. How would that work in a filter()?

Comment: Something like `df.filter(df("Date") >= date_sub(current_date(), 30))`, however, usally using `YYYY-mm-dd` format works better for such queries

Comment: That works. Thanks!

Comment: how would this filter help in selecting top 2 in group? @OneCricketeer

Comment: @A.B I was wondering about the same. The question has been changed by user7298979

Comment: Long story short, I thought I asked the question wrong, changed it, and realized my initial question was correct.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question because all your data is currently within the last 30 days, so all rows would be returned

Comment: @OneCricketeer sorry I didn't make it clear with the data. I've edited the question in the underlying data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [window](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?pyspark.sql.Window#pyspark.sql.Window) and take the top two [ranks](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?pyspark.sql.functions.rank#pyspark.sql.functions.rank) within each window:

```python
df.withColumn("r", F.rank().over(Window.partitionBy("Grouping", "Bucket") \
                           .orderBy(F.col("Date").desc()))) \
    .filter("r <=2") \
    .drop("r") \
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+------+----------+
|Grouping|Bucket|      Date|
+--------+------+----------+
|       1|     1|2020-09-20|
|       1|     1|2020-09-16|
|       1|     2|2020-09-20|
|       1|     2|2020-09-16|
|       2|     1|2020-09-20|
|       2|     1|2020-09-16|
+--------+------+----------+
```

Edit: this answer applies to [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64143337/4) (get the most recent N records for each group).